# can publish org ignore errors and push on

Tags: org-mode, org-publish

Currently I have a heap of org files which I publish into a knowledge base. Every once in a while a special character or some formatting will stop the publishing. Is it possible to ignore the error and push on with the rest of the files?

```
;; org publish options
(setq org-publish-project-alist
      '(
        ;; ... add all the components here (see below)...

        ;; All org files (notes)
        ("org-notes"
         :base-directory "~/org/business"
         :base-extension "org"
         :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/"
         :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html
         :headline-levels 4            
         :auto-preamble t
         :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />"
         )

        ;; Attachments
        ("org-static"
         :base-directory "~/org/"
         :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|htaccess"
         :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/"
         :recursive t
         :publishing-function org-publish-attachment
         )

        ;; Publish component
        ("org"
     :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))

      ))

; Create a little function to run publish mode in a shortcut
(defun puborg ()
  (interactive)
  (org-publish-project "org")
)
```

The error I get is;

```
Publishing file /home/map7/org/business/website.org using ‘org-html-publish-to-html’
apply: Wrong type argument: listp, #("Knowledge Base" 0 14 (:parent (#0)))
Saving file /home/map7/org/business/website.org...
Wrote /home/map7/org/business/website.org
```

If I remove the following line it works.

```
#+TITLE:   Website
```

**UPDATE: Add a small complete org file**

If I have an test.org file with the following

```
* Test publish org file

This file is to test the issue of publishing an org file which has a title.
```

Then everything publishes fine, then I change this test.org file to the following;

```
#+TITLE: Test publish org file

This file is to test the issue of publishing an org file which has a title.
```

Now with debugging mode on I try and publish and get the following error;

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument listp #("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent (#1))))
  org-element-set-contents(#("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent (#0))))
  apply(org-element-set-contents #("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent (#0))) nil)
  #[(s) "\306\307\310#\311\312  \211:\204\313\202\"@9\203!AA\202\")\"\210\314\315\n \211:\2043\313\202@@9\203?AA\202@)#\210 \316\211\n;\203V\317\320\f#\202\\\321A@\f\"*\211;\203n\322\313\f
$\202zA\323A@\f
#\240\210+\210\nA   A@\240\210\n    @\240*\207" [s new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 6](#("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent (#0))))
  #[(--data) "\211:\204 ;\205\306\202   @9\205  @)?\206\337\203,\307\310\">\206\337\n\2047\311\f\"\202\337\n\312=\203\\\311\f\211:\204J\313\202W    @9\203V AA\202W )\"\202\337\n
>\203\202!\211\203\201\203z\314\315\"\210\202\201B)\316=\203\312;\204\312\n\236A\313\211\203\311@\f ;\203\266\317\320   #\202\275\307   A@\"*!\210A\211\204\234*\203\202\316=\203\202\n>\203\202\313 \211\203\201@\211 @ A  ;\203\317\320   #\202\307   A@\"*!\"!\203w\"#\235\203_\"$\235\203P\321!!\313%\211\203L@%\f%A!\210\f%@!\210A\211\2042*\202w\f!A!\210\f!@!\210\202w\"$\235\203r\311\f\321!!\"\210\202w\f!!\210*A\211\204\350*\n&>\206\337\211:\204\224\313\202\241    @9\203\240  AA\202\241  )?\206\337\322=\203\265\n'>?\206\337\323=\203\303\n(>\206\337\311\f\211:\204\320\313\202\335    @9\203\334  AA\202\335  )\")\207" [--data element --type info --walk-tree types plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw --map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 reverse greater-elements elements fun result first-match --acc --category org-element-secondary-value-alist p --dolist-tail-- property with-affiliated org-element-all-elements org-element--parsed-properties-alist kwd-pair value kwd org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords line no-recursion org-element-greater-elements org-element-all-objects] 6](#("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent (#0))))
  mapc(#[(--data) "\211:\204    ;\205\306\202   @9\205  @)?\206\337\203,\307\310\">\206\337\n\2047\311\f\"\202\337\n\312=\203\\\311\f\211:\204J\313\202W    @9\203V AA\202W )\"\202\337\n
>\203\202!\211\203\201\203z\314\315\"\210\202\201B)\316=\203\312;\204\312\n\236A\313\211\203\311@\f ;\203\266\317\320   #\202\275\307   A@\"*!\210A\211\204\234*\203\202\316=\203\202\n>\203\202\313 \211\203\201@\211 @ A  ;\203\317\320   #\202\307   A@\"*!\"!\203w\"#\235\203_\"$\235\203P\321!!\313%\211\203L@%\f%A!\210\f%@!\210A\211\2042*\202w\f!A!\210\f!@!\210\202w\"$\235\203r\311\f\321!!\"\210\202w\f!!\210*A\211\204\350*\n&>\206\337\211:\204\224\313\202\241    @9\203\240  AA\202\241  )?\206\337\322=\203\265\n'>?\206\337\323=\203\303\n(>\206\337\311\f\211:\204\320\313\202\335    @9\203\334  AA\202\335  )\")\207" [--data element --type info --walk-tree types plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw --map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 reverse greater-elements elements fun result first-match --acc --category org-element-secondary-value-alist p --dolist-tail-- property with-affiliated org-element-all-elements org-element--parsed-properties-alist kwd-pair value kwd org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords line no-recursion org-element-greater-elements org-element-all-objects] 6] (#("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent #0))))
  #[(--data) "\211:\204 ;\205\306\202   @9\205  @)?\206\337\203,\307\310\">\206\337\n\2047\311\f\"\202\337\n\312=\203\\\311\f\211:\204J\313\202W    @9\203V AA\202W )\"\202\337\n
>\203\202!\211\203\201\203z\314\315\"\210\202\201B)\316=\203\312;\204\312\n\236A\313\211\203\311@\f ;\203\266\317\320   #\202\275\307   A@\"*!\210A\211\204\234*\203\202\316=\203\202\n>\203\202\313 \211\203\201@\211 @ A  ;\203\317\320   #\202\307   A@\"*!\"!\203w\"#\235\203_\"$\235\203P\321!!\313%\211\203L@%\f%A!\210\f%@!\210A\211\2042*\202w\f!A!\210\f!@!\210\202w\"$\235\203r\311\f\321!!\"\210\202w\f!!\210*A\211\204\350*\n&>\206\337\211:\204\224\313\202\241    @9\203\240  AA\202\241  )?\206\337\322=\203\265\n'>?\206\337\323=\203\303\n(>\206\337\311\f\211:\204\320\313\202\335    @9\203\334  AA\202\335  )\")\207" [--data element --type info --walk-tree types plain-text plist-get :ignore-list mapc org-data nil throw --map-first-match objects get-text-property 0 reverse greater-elements elements fun result first-match --acc --category org-element-secondary-value-alist p --dolist-tail-- property with-affiliated org-element-all-elements org-element--parsed-properties-alist kwd-pair value kwd org-element-dual-keywords org-element-multiple-keywords line no-recursion org-element-greater-elements org-element-all-objects] 6]((#("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent #0))))
  org-element-map((#("Test publish org file" 0 21 (:parent #0))) plain-text #[(s) "\306\307\310#\311\312    \211:\204\313\202\"@9\203!AA\202\")\"\210\314\315\n \211:\2043\313\202@@9\203?AA\202@)#\210 \316\211\n;\203V\317\320\f#\202\\\321A@\f\"*\211;\203n\322\313\f
$\202zA\323A@\f
#\240\210+\210\nA   A@\240\210\n    @\240*\207" [s new old element property value replace-regexp-in-string "\n" " " mapc #[(blob) "\305 \211;\203\306\f\307\n$\202 \fA\310\fA@\n#\240\210\f+\207" [blob old value property element :parent org-add-props nil plist-put] 6] nil apply org-element-set-contents :parent get-text-property 0 plist-get org-add-props plist-put] 6])
  org-export--get-inbuffer-options([cl-struct-org-export-backend html nil ((bold . org-html-bold) (center-block . org-html-center-block) (clock . org-html-clock) (code . org-html-code) (drawer . org-html-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-html-dynamic-block) (entity . org-html-entity) (example-block . org-html-example-block) (export-block . org-html-export-block) (export-snippet . org-html-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-html-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-html-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-html-footnote-reference) (headline . org-html-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-html-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-html-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-html-inlinetask) (inner-template . org-html-inner-template) (italic . org-html-italic) (item . org-html-item) (keyword . org-html-keyword) (latex-environment . org-html-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-html-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-html-line-break) (link . org-html-link) (node-property . org-html-node-property) (paragraph . org-html-paragraph) (plain-list . org-html-plain-list) (plain-text . org-html-plain-text) (planning . org-html-planning) (property-drawer . org-html-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-html-quote-block) (radio-target . org-html-radio-target) (section . org-html-section) (special-block . org-html-special-block) (src-block . org-html-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-html-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-html-strike-through) (subscript . org-html-subscript) (superscript . org-html-superscript) (table . org-html-table) (table-cell . org-html-table-cell) (table-row . org-html-table-row) (target . org-html-target) (template . org-html-template) (timestamp . org-html-timestamp) (underline . org-html-underline) (verbatim . org-html-verbatim) (verse-block . org-html-verse-block)) ((:html-doctype "HTML_DOCTYPE" nil org-html-doctype) (:html-container "HTML_CONTAINER" nil org-html-container-element) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil newline) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil space) (:html-html5-fancy nil "html5-fancy" org-html-html5-fancy) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-link-home "HTML_LINK_HOME" nil org-html-link-home) (:html-link-up "HTML_LINK_UP" nil org-html-link-up) (:html-mathjax "HTML_MATHJAX" nil "" space) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-postamble nil "html-postamble" org-html-postamble) (:html-preamble nil "html-preamble" org-html-preamble) (:html-head "HTML_HEAD" nil org-html-head newline) (:html-head-extra "HTML_HEAD_EXTRA" nil org-html-head-extra newline) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:html-head-include-default-style nil "html-style" org-html-head-include-default-style) (:html-head-include-scripts nil "html-scripts" org-html-head-include-scripts) (:html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors nil nil org-html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors) (:html-divs nil nil org-html-divs) (:html-checkbox-type nil nil org-html-checkbox-type) (:html-extension nil nil org-html-extension) (:html-footnote-format nil nil org-html-footnote-format) (:html-footnote-separator nil nil org-html-footnote-separator) (:html-footnotes-section nil nil org-html-footnotes-section) (:html-format-drawer-function nil nil org-html-format-drawer-function) (:html-format-headline-function nil nil org-html-format-headline-function) (:html-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-html-format-inlinetask-function) (:html-home/up-format nil nil org-html-home/up-format) (:html-indent nil nil org-html-indent) (:html-infojs-options nil nil org-html-infojs-options) (:html-infojs-template nil nil org-html-infojs-template) (:html-inline-image-rules nil nil org-html-inline-image-rules) (:html-link-org-files-as-html nil nil org-html-link-org-files-as-html) (:html-mathjax-options nil nil org-html-mathjax-options) (:html-mathjax-template nil nil org-html-mathjax-template) (:html-metadata-timestamp-format nil nil org-html-metadata-timestamp-format) (:html-postamble-format nil nil org-html-postamble-format) (:html-preamble-format nil nil org-html-preamble-format) (:html-table-align-individual-fields nil nil org-html-table-align-individual-fields) (:html-table-caption-above nil nil org-html-table-caption-above) (:html-table-data-tags nil nil org-html-table-data-tags) (:html-table-header-tags nil nil org-html-table-header-tags) (:html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column nil nil org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column) (:html-tag-class-prefix nil nil org-html-tag-class-prefix) (:html-text-markup-alist nil nil org-html-text-markup-alist) (:html-todo-kwd-class-prefix nil nil org-html-todo-kwd-class-prefix) (:html-toplevel-hlevel nil nil org-html-toplevel-hlevel) (:html-use-infojs nil nil org-html-use-infojs) (:html-validation-link nil nil org-html-validation-link) (:html-viewport nil nil org-html-viewport) ...) ((:filter-options . org-html-infojs-install-script) (:filter-final-output . org-html-final-function)) ("HTML") (104 "Export to HTML" ((72 "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html) (104 "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html) (111 "As HTML file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))])
  org-export-get-environment([cl-struct-org-export-backend html nil ((bold . org-html-bold) (center-block . org-html-center-block) (clock . org-html-clock) (code . org-html-code) (drawer . org-html-drawer) (dynamic-block . org-html-dynamic-block) (entity . org-html-entity) (example-block . org-html-example-block) (export-block . org-html-export-block) (export-snippet . org-html-export-snippet) (fixed-width . org-html-fixed-width) (footnote-definition . org-html-footnote-definition) (footnote-reference . org-html-footnote-reference) (headline . org-html-headline) (horizontal-rule . org-html-horizontal-rule) (inline-src-block . org-html-inline-src-block) (inlinetask . org-html-inlinetask) (inner-template . org-html-inner-template) (italic . org-html-italic) (item . org-html-item) (keyword . org-html-keyword) (latex-environment . org-html-latex-environment) (latex-fragment . org-html-latex-fragment) (line-break . org-html-line-break) (link . org-html-link) (node-property . org-html-node-property) (paragraph . org-html-paragraph) (plain-list . org-html-plain-list) (plain-text . org-html-plain-text) (planning . org-html-planning) (property-drawer . org-html-property-drawer) (quote-block . org-html-quote-block) (radio-target . org-html-radio-target) (section . org-html-section) (special-block . org-html-special-block) (src-block . org-html-src-block) (statistics-cookie . org-html-statistics-cookie) (strike-through . org-html-strike-through) (subscript . org-html-subscript) (superscript . org-html-superscript) (table . org-html-table) (table-cell . org-html-table-cell) (table-row . org-html-table-row) (target . org-html-target) (template . org-html-template) (timestamp . org-html-timestamp) (underline . org-html-underline) (verbatim . org-html-verbatim) (verse-block . org-html-verse-block)) ((:html-doctype "HTML_DOCTYPE" nil org-html-doctype) (:html-container "HTML_CONTAINER" nil org-html-container-element) (:description "DESCRIPTION" nil nil newline) (:keywords "KEYWORDS" nil nil space) (:html-html5-fancy nil "html5-fancy" org-html-html5-fancy) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-link-home "HTML_LINK_HOME" nil org-html-link-home) (:html-link-up "HTML_LINK_UP" nil org-html-link-up) (:html-mathjax "HTML_MATHJAX" nil "" space) (:html-link-use-abs-url nil "html-link-use-abs-url" org-html-link-use-abs-url) (:html-postamble nil "html-postamble" org-html-postamble) (:html-preamble nil "html-preamble" org-html-preamble) (:html-head "HTML_HEAD" nil org-html-head newline) (:html-head-extra "HTML_HEAD_EXTRA" nil org-html-head-extra newline) (:subtitle "SUBTITLE" nil nil parse) (:html-head-include-default-style nil "html-style" org-html-head-include-default-style) (:html-head-include-scripts nil "html-scripts" org-html-head-include-scripts) (:html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors nil nil org-html-allow-name-attribute-in-anchors) (:html-divs nil nil org-html-divs) (:html-checkbox-type nil nil org-html-checkbox-type) (:html-extension nil nil org-html-extension) (:html-footnote-format nil nil org-html-footnote-format) (:html-footnote-separator nil nil org-html-footnote-separator) (:html-footnotes-section nil nil org-html-footnotes-section) (:html-format-drawer-function nil nil org-html-format-drawer-function) (:html-format-headline-function nil nil org-html-format-headline-function) (:html-format-inlinetask-function nil nil org-html-format-inlinetask-function) (:html-home/up-format nil nil org-html-home/up-format) (:html-indent nil nil org-html-indent) (:html-infojs-options nil nil org-html-infojs-options) (:html-infojs-template nil nil org-html-infojs-template) (:html-inline-image-rules nil nil org-html-inline-image-rules) (:html-link-org-files-as-html nil nil org-html-link-org-files-as-html) (:html-mathjax-options nil nil org-html-mathjax-options) (:html-mathjax-template nil nil org-html-mathjax-template) (:html-metadata-timestamp-format nil nil org-html-metadata-timestamp-format) (:html-postamble-format nil nil org-html-postamble-format) (:html-preamble-format nil nil org-html-preamble-format) (:html-table-align-individual-fields nil nil org-html-table-align-individual-fields) (:html-table-caption-above nil nil org-html-table-caption-above) (:html-table-data-tags nil nil org-html-table-data-tags) (:html-table-header-tags nil nil org-html-table-header-tags) (:html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column nil nil org-html-table-use-header-tags-for-first-column) (:html-tag-class-prefix nil nil org-html-tag-class-prefix) (:html-text-markup-alist nil nil org-html-text-markup-alist) (:html-todo-kwd-class-prefix nil nil org-html-todo-kwd-class-prefix) (:html-toplevel-hlevel nil nil org-html-toplevel-hlevel) (:html-use-infojs nil nil org-html-use-infojs) (:html-validation-link nil nil org-html-validation-link) (:html-viewport nil nil org-html-viewport) ...) ((:filter-options . org-html-infojs-install-script) (:filter-final-output . org-html-final-function)) ("HTML") (104 "Export to HTML" ((72 "As HTML buffer" org-html-export-as-html) (104 "As HTML file" org-html-export-to-html) (111 "As HTML file and open" (lambda (a s v b) (if a (org-html-export-to-html t s v b) (org-open-file (org-html-export-to-html nil s v b)))))))] nil (:output-file "/var/www/manual/test.html" :base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :filter-final-output (org-publish--collect-references org-publish-collect-index)))
  org-export-as(html nil nil nil (:output-file "/var/www/manual/test.html" :base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :filter-final-output (org-publish--collect-references org-publish-collect-index)))
  org-export-to-file(html "/var/www/manual/test.html" nil nil nil nil (:base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :filter-final-output (org-publish--collect-references org-publish-collect-index)))
  org-publish-org-to(html "/home/map7/org/business/test.org" ".html" (:base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />") "/var/www/manual/")
  org-html-publish-to-html((:base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />") "/home/map7/org/business/test.org" "/var/www/manual/")
  org-publish-file("/home/map7/org/business/test.org" ("org-notes" :base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />") t)
  #[(project) "\306@!\210A\307  \310\"\307  \311\"\307  \312\"\206\313\307  \314\"\206#\315\307 \316\"\206-\307 \317\"\2068  \307   \320\"\307  \321\"\322\n\"!\323\324\307 \325\"\"\"\203^\326\327!\210\203g
\f\"\210!\330#\211$\203\216$@\211#\"\232\204\205\331#\332#\210$A\211$\204r*\307 \333\"\203\245\334\307  \325\"\"\210\331\"\332#\210\203\256\326\335!\210\336 .\207" [project project-plist exclude-regexp sitemap-p sitemap-filename sitemap-function org-publish-initialize-cache plist-get :exclude :auto-sitemap :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org" :sitemap-function org-publish-org-sitemap :sitemap-date-format :sitemap-file-entry-format :preparation-function :completion-function org-publish-get-base-files expand-file-name "theindex.org" :base-directory run-hooks preparation-function nil org-publish-file t :makeindex org-publish-index-generate-theindex completion-function org-publish-write-cache-file org-publish-sitemap-date-format org-publish-sitemap-file-entry-format files theindex file --dolist-tail--] 6](("org-notes" :base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />"))
  mapc(#[(project) "\306@!\210A\307 \310\"\307  \311\"\307  \312\"\206\313\307  \314\"\206#\315\307 \316\"\206-\307 \317\"\2068  \307   \320\"\307  \321\"\322\n\"!\323\324\307 \325\"\"\"\203^\326\327!\210\203g
\f\"\210!\330#\211$\203\216$@\211#\"\232\204\205\331#\332#\210$A\211$\204r*\307 \333\"\203\245\334\307  \325\"\"\210\331\"\332#\210\203\256\326\335!\210\336 .\207" [project project-plist exclude-regexp sitemap-p sitemap-filename sitemap-function org-publish-initialize-cache plist-get :exclude :auto-sitemap :sitemap-filename "sitemap.org" :sitemap-function org-publish-org-sitemap :sitemap-date-format :sitemap-file-entry-format :preparation-function :completion-function org-publish-get-base-files expand-file-name "theindex.org" :base-directory run-hooks preparation-function nil org-publish-file t :makeindex org-publish-index-generate-theindex completion-function org-publish-write-cache-file org-publish-sitemap-date-format org-publish-sitemap-file-entry-format files theindex file --dolist-tail--] 6] (("org-notes" :base-directory "~/org/business" :base-extension "org" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :style "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />" :recursive t :publishing-function org-html-publish-to-html :headline-levels 4 :auto-preamble t :html-head "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"css/stylesheet.css\" type=\"text/css\" />") ("org-static" :base-directory "~/org/" :base-extension "css\\|js\\|png\\|jpg\\|gif\\|pdf\\|mp3\\|ogg\\|swf\\|htaccess" :publishing-directory "/var/www/manual/" :recursive t :publishing-function org-publish-attachment)))
  org-publish-projects((("org" :components ("org-notes" "org-static"))))
  org-publish-project("org")
  puborg()
  funcall-interactively(puborg)
  call-interactively(puborg record nil)
  command-execute(puborg record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "puborg")
  smex-read-and-run(("org-publish" "magit-version" "toggle-debug-on-error" "eval-buffer" "slack-im-open" "slack-mode" "slack-start" "org-insert-link" "puborg" "ispell-word" "sudo-edit" "package-list-packages" "find-name-dired" "list-packages" "rotate-windows" "about-emacs" "bundle-outdated" "hide-sublevels" "javascript-mode" "package-install" "winner-undo" "org-screenshot" "volume" "multi-term" "org-table-sum" "org-toggle-inline-images" "twit" "magit-tag" "upcase-word" "paradox-list-packages" "term-send-esc" "magit-reset-hard" "size-indication-mode" "togetherly-server-start" "projectile-rails-console" "org-reveal-export-to-html-and-browse" "ispell" "calendar" "sql-postgres" "projectile-rails-mode" "linum-mode" "org-attach" "company-restclient" "ansible" "rbenv-use" "ruby-mode" "magit-diff" "crontab-mode" "menu-bar-mode" "query-replace" ...))
  smex()
  funcall-interactively(smex)
  call-interactively(smex nil nil)
  command-execute(smex)
```

Comment: A minimal reproducible example of the problem would be really useful here - i.e., a small, complete org file that generates the error, not just a single line that may cause the problem.  Or may not, if there's something else interacting.