# Org-publish: Ignore errors when publishing and report them later

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-publish

I feel that `org-publish` is not user-friendly in the sense that once it fails, it straightly stops. Unfortunately, there are dozens of reasons `org-publish` might fail. To name a few:

- `org-export--inclusion-absolute-lines`: No match for fuzzy expression: `*XXX` for `/path/to/file.org::*XXX`
- Executing `bibtex2html` failed
- Can't find footnote definition
- Broken links
- Custom package export function failed
- Babel Emacs lisp code failed
  ...
  *etc*.

I believe that most of the people don't have the time to debug all kind of little details through hundreds Org files and rerun `org-publish` until it is happy. Each intervention to fix one of those errors requires time ranging from few seconds to few minutes which is not realistic to do when one is in a hurry.

I'm aware that there is a [:with-broken-links](https://orgmode.org/manual/Publishing-options.html#Publishing-options) property, but it is not the only reason `org-publish` would halt as stated above.

**Question 1**. Is there any way to let `org-publish` ignore errors (at worst not publishing the Org file in question at all) and simply step forward ?

**Question 2**. If so, it is possible to report error per a file basis ? Something like:

```
| /path/to/file1.org | `org-export--inclusion-absolute-lines`: No match for fuzzy expression: `*XXX` for `/path/to/file.org::*XXX` |
| /path/to/file1.org | Can't find footnote definition |
| /path/to/file2.org | Executing `bibtex2html` failed |
```

Related questions:

1. [Can publish org ignore errors and push on](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26084/can-publish-org-ignore-errors-and-push-on)
2. [org-publish-project fails because of defective org-links - repair links automatically or ignore them?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/52232/org-publish-project-fails-because-of-defective-org-links-repair-links-automati)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this?

Comment: @ngm Sorry, I moved on...